# Animate a single element that's on a page more than once

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, css, jquery-animate

I'm not even sure I asked that question the right, I'm a jQuery newb.

But here's my scenario, I built this CSS3/jQuery social share button to use on WordPress posts, it works great on a single post page. The problem occurs when I'm on the home page or any other archive page where they're multiple instances of the share button. I'm using jQuery to animate the button, so when it's clicked the share button opens up.

The problem is when there's more than one share button, they all open up on the page, it's chaos.

Here's a demo link:

http://best5ive.com/wp-content/themes/b5/library/sexy-share1.html

How do I open one share button at a time and close it when another one is opened? Like the way it is on AskMen.com.

Here's my code thus far, pardon the silly name.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sexy-widget">

    <a class="sexy-button" alt="Sexy Share" title="Sexy Share"></a>
      <div class="sexy-network-wrapper">
            <a class="sexy-facebook"></a>
            <a class="sexy-twitter"></a>
            <a class="sexy-googleplus"></a>
            <a class="sexy-pinterest"></a>
            <a class="sexy-linkedin"></a>
            <a class="sexy-email"></a>                
        </div>

</div>

<div class="sexy-widget">

    <a class="sexy-button" alt="Sexy Share" title="Sexy Share"></a>
      <div class="sexy-network-wrapper">
            <a class="sexy-facebook"></a>
            <a class="sexy-twitter"></a>
            <a class="sexy-googleplus"></a>
            <a class="sexy-pinterest"></a>
            <a class="sexy-linkedin"></a>
            <a class="sexy-email"></a>                
        </div>

</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$( "a.sexy-button" ).toggle(
function()
{
  $( ".sexy-email" ).delay(100).animate({ top: "0px", left: "81px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".sexy-facebook" ).delay(200).animate({ top: "40px", left: "0px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".sexy-twitter" ).delay(300).animate({ top: "120px", left: "0px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".sexy-pinterest" ).delay(400).animate({ bottom: "0px", left: "81px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".sexy-linkedin" ).delay(500).animate({ top: "120px", right: "0px" }, "slow" );
  $( ".sexy-googleplus" ).delay(600).animate({ top: "40px", right: "0px" }, "slow" );
  $( "a.sexy-button" ).removeClass("rotateReverse").addClass( "animated rotateIn orange-share" );
},
function()
   {
    $( ".sexy-email" ).animate({ top: "80px", left: "80px" }, "slow" );
    $( ".sexy-facebook" ).animate({ top: "80px", left: "80px" }, "slow" );
    $( ".sexy-twitter" ).animate({ top: "80px", left: "80px" }, "slow" );
    $( ".sexy-pinterest" ).animate({ bottom: "80px", left: "80px" }, "slow" );
    $( ".sexy-linkedin" ).animate({ top: "80px", right: "80px" }, "slow" );
    $( ".sexy-googleplus" ).animate({ top: "80px", right: "80px" }, "slow" );
    $( "a.sexy-button" ).addClass("rotateReverse").removeClass( "rotateIn orange-share" );
    });
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to use `this` inside the click handler to target the instance that was clicked rather than targeting them all. Additionally, that usage of .toggle is deprecated and removed in newer versions of jquery.

Comment: you are using jquery 1.10.1, toggle event has been removed

Comment: @A.Wolff he's using wordpress, i'd be surprised if there weren't more than 3 versions of jquery included. If one of his buttons are working, he must be using an older version too.

Comment: I just checked in linked site using `$.fn.jquery`  PS: sorry, misread your comment ;)  BTW, OP is using jquery migrate, that explains it all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is your adopted code:

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$( "a.sexy-button" ).click(function() {
        var block = $(this).parent();
        if (!$(this).hasClass('animated')) {
            block.find( ".sexy-email" ).delay(100).animate({ top: "0px", left: "81px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-facebook" ).delay(200).animate({ top: "40px", left: "0px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-twitter" ).delay(300).animate({ top: "120px", left: "0px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-pinterest" ).delay(400).animate({ bottom: "0px", left: "81px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-linkedin" ).delay(500).animate({ top: "120px", right: "0px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-googleplus" ).delay(600).animate({ top: "40px", right: "0px" }, "slow" );
            $(this).removeClass("rotateReverse").addClass( "animated rotateIn orange-share" );  
        }
        else {

            block.find( ".sexy-email" ).animate({ top: "80px", left: "80px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-facebook" ).animate({ top: "80px", left: "80px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-twitter" ).animate({ top: "80px", left: "80px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-pinterest" ).animate({ bottom: "80px", left: "80px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-linkedin" ).animate({ top: "80px", right: "80px" }, "slow" );
            block.find( ".sexy-googleplus" ).animate({ top: "80px", right: "80px" }, "slow" );
            $(this).addClass("rotateReverse").removeClass( "rotateIn orange-share" );

        }

    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I tried your suggestion and it worked half way. The animation only works on the first click, after the button closes, it can't be opened again nor does the other share bottom close when the other one opens. I created a fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/Covanant/3hq4D/22/

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot man, now I just have to figure out how to close one when the other is open.

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot man. You've gone above and beyond, I was actually just doing it, but my method was much more complicated, I'm always over thinking it when comes to jQuery. That's what happens when you learn it in fragments as oppose to taking a course I guess. Thanks again.